# Pusher responses correctly on JavaScript, but does not work on Nodejs, though the code are almost same

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin, pusher

I write the code about webSocket for chain.so ( https://chain.so/api).
Chain.so offers the realtime response with some event.

I write the code like below on JavaScript, it works correctly.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pusher/2.1.6/pusher.min.js"></script>

<script>
Pusher.host = 'slanger1.chain.so'; // our server
Pusher.ws_port = 443; // our server's port
Pusher.wss_port = 443; // ...

// create the pusher client connection
var pusher = new Pusher('e9f5cc20074501ca7395', { encrypted: true,    disabledTransports: ['sockjs'], disableStats: true }); 
var ticker =  pusher.subscribe('address_btctest_mwXpb9fkD2TVSwv64CAHB4ZSEjQVNpR9z3');

ticker.bind('balance_update', function(data) {
   console.log("success");
});
```

This code is very useful, because can alert whenever bitcoin recieves.
However, the similar code for nodejs does not work.
The Nodejs code is below

```
var Pusher = require('pusher-client');

Pusher.host = 'slanger1.chain.so'; // our server
Pusher.ws_port = 443; // our server's port
Pusher.wss_port = 443; // ...

// create the pusher client connection
var pusher = new Pusher('e9f5cc20074501ca7395', { encrypted: true, disabledTransports: ['sockjs'], disableStats: true });
var ticker = socket.subscribe('address_btctest_mwXpb9fkD2TVSwv64CAHB4ZSEjQVNpR9z3');
pusher.bind('balance_update', function(data) {
      console.log("success");
});
```

These two codes are almost same, but doesn't work for Nodejs.
What is wrong on second code? Give me help.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "does not work"? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: response nothing when using nodejs, though in JavaScript , response the info about new transaction the address received.